# create a alias type from a const generic type

Tags: rust

warning : this is nighly rust. You need to do this command line: `rustup default nightly`
(and `rustup default stable` to go back to your previous configurtion)

I Would like to define a type from another type.
If I create a type from a const generic type (See 1), it works.
But if I create a const generic type from another const generic type, it doesn't work (see 2)

What should I do?

```rust
#![feature(const_generics)]

struct Board<T, const WIDTH: usize, const HEIGHT: usize> {
    array: [[T; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
}

type a = Board<i32,3,3>; // works (1)

type SquareBoard<T, const Dim: usize> = Board<T,WIDTH=Dim,HEIGHT=Dim>;  // doesn't work (2)
```

Comment: @trentcl . No. Now I've modified my question. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you do not have to spell out the const parameter names (just as you do not spell out type parameter names):

```
#![feature(const_generics)]

struct Board<T, const WIDTH: usize, const HEIGHT: usize> {
    array: [[T; WIDTH]; HEIGHT],
}

type a = Board<i32,3,3>; // works (1)

type SquareBoard<T, const Dim: usize> = Board<T, Dim, Dim>;  // works (2)
```